# How to Replace a RGB Value on a Texture2D on Monogame?

Tags: c#, monogame, texture2d

I'm working with C# and Monogame 3.2.
I'm currently working on a 2D game, such like Starbound, and I need to have the blocks connect to each other and when not, have some fancy borders.
What I am doing is I have a texture that covers the whole 32*32 image, and a custom function named "trimImage" to trim the image so it has fancy borders.
But, I need to find a way to set a transparent pixel at a specific pixel in a Texture2D so I can make that border.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RJMC.png
See the purple dirt, I bassicly want it to trim the image to something like that, and when other blocks are connecting to it it will connect.

Does anyone know how, or atleast a better way to do this "border" effect? Thanks.

Note: In my trim class I really do have is just some comments, nothing else.

Comment: Not really sure if this is what you are trying to do, but it may be of help to you:  http://www.jgallant.com/auto-calculating-bounding-box-from-texture-in-monogame-xna/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you want your border to look like, but you can do a color replacement like this using the Texture2D.GetData() functions:

```
private Color TRANSPARENT = Color.Transparent;
private Color BAD_COLOR = Color.Purple;
private const int DEVIATION = 10;

public Texture2D trimImage(Texture2D texture)
{
    /// Get the data from the original texture and place it in an array
    Color[] colorData = new Color[texture.Width * texture.Height];
    texture.GetData<Color>(colorData);

    /// Loop through the array and change the RGB values you choose
    for (int x = 0; x < texture.Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < texture.Height; y++)
        {
            Color pixel = colorData[x * texture.Height + y];
            /// Check if the color is within the range
            if (MathHelper.Distance(pixel.R, BAD_COLOR.R) < DEVIATION &&
                MathHelper.Distance(pixel.G, BAD_COLOR.G) < DEVIATION &&
                MathHelper.Distance(pixel.B, BAD_COLOR.B) < DEVIATION &&
                pixel.A != 0f)
            {
                /// Make that color transparent
                pixel = TRANSPARENT;
            }
        }
    }

    /// Put the color array into the new texture and return it
    texture.SetData<Color>(colorData);
    return texture;
}
```

Being able to make a different border is just a matter of changing loop parameters and choosing the appropriate pixels. Hope it helps